# Select box disable self on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to disable a select box, when user select something.
Javascript code:

```js
function desabilitar(val) {
    $(val).attr('disabled','disabled');
}
```

HTML:

```html
<select class="form-control" onchange="desabilitar('mes')"  id="mes" name="mes">
```

But is not working... Any help?

Comment: Why would you do this? That's going to be very annoying for users who make a mistake, or for people who used the keyboard to tab to the select and pressed the down arrow key to try to move through the list of options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function desabilitar(val) {
 document.getElementById(val).disabled = true;
}
```

The same with jQuery:

```
function desabilitar(val) {
  $("#" + val).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

Do you want to use jQuery or JavaScript? In your question you are asking for JavaScript but you are using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `prop` and not `attr`, and make sure you select the attribute by the id using '#':

Example:

```js
function desabilitar(val) {
  $('#'+val).prop('disabled', true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" onchange="desabilitar('mes')"  id="mes" name="mes">
  <option>123</option>
  <option>456</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `"#" +` to before `val`. This will make sure you are looking for an element with the id that is val.

```js
function desabilitar(val) {
  $("#" + val).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" onchange="desabilitar('mes')" id="mes" name="mes">
  <option>Test 1</option>
  <option>Test 2</option>
  <option>Test 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a # to correctly get an element by its id and set the disabled attribute, like so:

```
function desabilitar(val) {
$("#"+val).attr('disabled','disabled');

}
```

Comment: Great! I'm glad to help. JQuery needs a # for getting ids, a . for getting classes, and no delimiter for getting all of a certain element type. I'm sure you know this, but it's always good to remember.